# PHP doctrine form validation without submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, doctrine-orm

I am using php, jquery, zend framework2 and doctrine annotation.

For submitting the form, I need to use ajax to post the data.

But then, doctrine's form validation does not work!

I used `type=button` instead of `type=submit`. then it does not trigger the validation at all.

I used `type=submit`, and tried to return false to avoid page refresh, but this also did not work.

Is there really a way to trigger form validation event using a javascript or jquery call.

Comment: Why not validate with jquery directly + php (return json on ajax post)?

Comment: At least you have to post sample code